# Facebook Marketing - Story Image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

When creating a **Facebook Campaign** though **UI** (Business Manager) there's a way to set an **alternative picture for a group**, so for example you can set different dimensions picture to display in the stories. However when creating same campaign using API calls, looks like there's no way for doing so? I can only have one image for an Ad Creative.

Can someone point me towards a right direction? Code sample or just an explanation of what objects needs to be created in order to achieve the result?

Here's what I'm writing about when having it about image-groups whet using Facebook UI:
[image]

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope, I didn't, did you? @phper